# How to add circles as markers to mapbox in android?

Tags: java, android, mapbox-android

I need a circle(with some color to distinguish ) as location marker (not like an image) in map box. When we zoom in the map box circle should be increased and when we are zooming out it should decrease size.

This is my code. It is showing default image by mapbox icon, but I don't want it. It should be replace by circle :

```
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
 options.setTitle(title)
 options.setPosition(new LatLng(Latitude ,Longitude));
 options.snippet("this is stack location ");
 mapboxMap.addMarker(options);
```